# TypeError: results.map is not a function Function.renderemployeeTable

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, visual-studio-code, react-redux

I was trying to display api data using reactJs Application. i used the following code but i keep getting the following error

> TypeError: results.map is not a function
>       Function.renderemployeeTable

export class FetchData extends Component {
        static displayName = FetchData.name;

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { results: [] };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
           fetch('urll', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'api-key': 'api-key'  
            }
        })
            .then(results => results.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({ results: data }));
    }
    static renderemployeeTable(results) {
        return (

            <div class="container-fluid" class="row" fluid={true}>
                {
                    results.map(results =>
                        <div class="col-sm-3" key={results.Employee_Number}>
                            <div class="card our-team" >
                                <div class="card-body">

                                    <p class="card-text">{results.first_name}</p>
                                    <p class="card-text">{results.last_name}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Detail</a>
                        </div>
                    )
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
    render() {
        let contents = this.state.loading
            ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
            : FetchData.renderemployeeTable(this.state.results);

        return (
            <div>
                <h1 id="tabelLabel" >-</h1>


                {contents}
            </div>
        );

    }
    async populateemployeeData() {
        const response = await fetch('table');
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({ results: data, loading: false });
    }
}
```

but i get this error message

```
TypeError: results.map is not a function
Function.renderemployeeTable
```

This is the output of console.log(results).

```
"data": {
 "Table": [
 {
 "id": 14258,
 "first_name": "yibgeta",
 "last_name": "solans",...
  }]}],
```

Comment: try to put console.log(results) inside renderemployeeTable and see what basically it returns?

Comment: @tareqaziz how can i do that? i'm a newbie

Comment: try this way

`static renderemployeeTable(results) {
 console.log(results);
 return (...) 
}`

Comment: ok i will, thanks @tareqaziz here the sample copied from postman `"data": {
 "Table": [
 {
 "id": 14258,
 "first_name": "yibgeta",
 "last_name": "solans",..` if i have any idea

Comment: Then I think your map should be like `results.data.Table.map( result =>...`

Answer (score 0):

Did you have ever try to write down like this?

```
data => this.setState({
  results: data.Table
})
```

Or

```
results.Table.map(result => ...)
```

Comment: @Kuku I changed my solution

Answer (score 0):

Now it will work------

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { results: [] };
}

componentDidMount() {
       fetch('http://web.api.services/api/v2/tultula/employees/all', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'api-key': '7cefc4163dula77bf0f41ba741c'  
        }
    })
        .then(results => results.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ results: data }));
}



  render() {
              if(this.state.result != null && this.state.result!= undefined){
   return (

        <div class="container-fluid" class="row" fluid={true}>
            {
                this.state.results.map(results =>
                    <div class="col-sm-3" key={results.Employee_Number}>
                        <div class="card our-team" >
                            <div class="card-body">

                                <p class="card-text">{results.first_name}</p>
                                <p class="card-text">{results.last_name}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Detail</a>
                    </div>
                )
            }
        </div>
    );}

    let contents = this.state.loading
        ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
        : FetchData.renderemployeeTable(this.state.results);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1 id="tabelLabel" >-</h1>


            {contents}
        </div>
    );

}
async populateemployeeData() {
    const response = await fetch('table');
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ results: data, loading: false });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way:-

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { results: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("url", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "api-key": "api-key"
      }
    })
      .then(results => results.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ results: data }));
  }

  renderemployeeTable(results) {
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid" className="row" fluid={true}>
        {results.map(results => (
          <div className="col-sm-3" key={results.Employee_Number}>
            <div className="card our-team">
              <div className="card-body">
                <p className="card-text">{results.first_name}</p>
                <p className="card-text">{results.last_name}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#" className="btn btn-primary">
              Detail
            </a>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
  render() {
    let contents = this.state.loading ? (
      <p>
        <em>Loading...</em>
      </p>
    ) : (
      this.renderemployeeTable(this.state.results)
    );

    return (
      <div>
        <h1 id="tabelLabel">-</h1>

        {contents}
      </div>
    );
  }
  async populateemployeeData() {
    const response = await fetch("table");
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ results: data, loading: false });
  }
}

export default Example;
```

Comment: I tried that but no luck I updated the sample data from postman

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
{
    results.Table && results.Table.map( result =>...)
}
```

This will ensure that the array exists and then you can use map function on it.